# "No need to update index.yaml" floods console

Tags: google-app-engine

At the moment as I debug my App Engine server, I'm often starting it up with the instruction to clear the datastore and then firing a couple of KB of data at it in the hope of figuring out why some of the reports I've written aren't generating properly.

However one thing that's getting in the way of the development and also raising some slight concern is that the console floods with the following output:

```
DEBUG    2012-07-13 11:44:34,033 datastore_stub_index.py:181] No need to update index.yaml
DEBUG    2012-07-13 11:44:34,221 datastore_stub_index.py:181] No need to update index.yaml
DEBUG    2012-07-13 11:44:34,406 datastore_stub_index.py:181] No need to update index.yaml
DEBUG    2012-07-13 11:44:34,601 datastore_stub_index.py:181] No need to update index.yaml
```

I've got two questions: should I be concerned about the flood of messages that are indicating that index.yaml does not need to be changed, and if not, is there a way to surpress the warning? If I should be concerned, could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

It's no need for concern and just indicates that the devserver doesn't need to add new items to the index.yaml file. This is explained in more detail [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig#About_index_yaml).

> Every datastore query made by an application needs a corresponding
>   index. Indexes for complex queries must be defined in a configuration
>   file named index.yaml.
>
> The development web server automatically adds items to this file when
>   the application tries to execute a query that needs an index that does
>   not have an appropriate entry in the configuration file.

If I'm not mistaken this should only be printed when the `--debug` flag is passed to the devserver, so maybe it set as an option in the tool you use to invoke the devserver.